# java JComboBox with date selection

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to create a `dropdown` box for selection dates, each selection will have its own box. I am doing it the way below, but is really inefficient. This doesn't work also because my `JComboBox` objects cannot accept the different arrays. I can't use a downloaded imported library either.

```
String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
int[] days = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
int[] year ={1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015};
JComboBox cmb = new JComboBox(months);
JComboBox cmbdays = new JComboBox(days);    
JComboBox cmbyears = new JComboBox(year);
```

Comment: What are you going to do when someone selects Feb 31, 2013?  A JCalendar component is the most efficient for entering dates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SwingX Library which contains a very user-friendly calendar component.

https://swingx.java.net/